# Window.Location to the same page PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, reload

I have a button which puts an item to my cart. How can I set my Window.Location button to the same page without Reloading it infinitely after click the button so I can continue browsing adding items to my cart. Here is my code.

```
 echo '<script>window.location.reload()</script>';
```

The above codes keeps reloading. I just need the item to add the cart and continue browsing.

Comment: you'd have to show how/where this code gets called.

Comment: Why is JS involved at all? Just make the button a submit button in a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='#' onclick='callfunction(); window.location="thispage.php";' title='close'>button</a>
```

But since it's from PHP, why not use header?

```
header('refresh:10;thispage.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` in order to redirect it to the same page that you need provide you must be sure with the url that give.

```
<a href='#' onclick="callfunction();" title='close'>button</a>
```

And the `JS file` you can have it like this.

```
function callfunction()
{
   window.location= 'your-page.php';
}
```

The basic difference between the `window.location` and `window.location.href` is

`window.location` - This will add the location to the current page that you are browsing or looking for.

`window.location.href` - This will reload the page that you are giving in the URL over here.